# Jenkins not running sh commands on windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, sh, jenkins-groovy

When running a sh-command inside of a jenkins pipeline, the commands themselves are not running.

The shell is part of my PATH-variable, thus the cmd-prompt is running, but the commands are not.

Code inside pipeline:

```
sh "echo Hello World"
bat "echo Hello World"
```

Result:

```
[Pipeline] sh
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.657]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Alle rechten voorbehouden.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testCI>
[Pipeline] bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\testCI>echo Hello World 
Hello World
```

How do I get the sh-commands to run?
I'd rather not rely on bat, as this pipeline (and jenkins-workspace) will be moved to a UNIX-environment in the future

Answer (score 0):

Try installing either git bash or cygwin. Sh and Bash executables come by default with them.

You can use path to that sh file here.

Comment: I'm using Git bash in my PATH-variable.
It's running the shell, just not the command

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a Windows 10 agent, I recommend installing a Linux subsystem since you plan on moving to a similar environment in the future. However, this would require you to reinstall Jenkins in that subsystem, but it would behave how it would on any other UNIX system out of the gate without having to configure and manage third-party software that is not guaranteed to work on Windows (with Jenkins) as it does on UNIX systems.

You can install a new Jenkins master on the Linux subsystem while keeping the Windows master intact, and then migrate users over when it is configured the way you want it to be.

**Installing WSL**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: Jenkins will eventually run inside of a Docker container.. However, during setup of the pipeline it's running locally on a Win-10 machine. 
Setting it up in Linux (or a container) seems like 'overkill' just to get SH to accept my commands..

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the problem where sh-command inside of a jenkins pipeline was resulting into exception. I'm using Jenkins in Windows OS and below steps solved the problem -

1. Installed Git Bash
2. Set environment variable PATH for "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" and "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"
3. Restart the Jenkins server
4. Build your pipeline.

You should be good to execute sh command in Jenkins Pipeline.